# TypeError: Invalid shape (100, 100, 1) for image data When plot image

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, matplotlib

I try to plot Images with 100,100,1 but got an error like this

```
TypeError: Invalid shape (100, 100, 1) for image data
```

here is the code

```
sample_training_images, _ = next(traindata)
def plotImages(images_arr):
    fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, 5, figsize=(20,20))
    axes = axes.flatten()
    for img, ax in zip( images_arr, axes):
        ax.imshow(img)
        ax.axis('off')
    plt.tight_layout()
    plt.plot(images_arr)
    plt.show()

plotImages(sample_training_images[:5])
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Replace `img` with `img[:,:,0]`:

```
 ax.imshow(img[:,:,0], cmap='gray')
```

And probably remove the `plt.plot(images_arr)`

Comment: still got the same error, I delete the plt.plot(image_arr) and change the plt.show() into your answer but sill. The error points out in the plotImages line

Comment: @SmurfAgain try `plt.imshow(images_arr[:,:,0], cmap='gray')`.

Comment: the error points out in plotImages(sample_training_images[:5] with the same error, I try to change the plt.show with your answer but still

Comment: @SmurfAgain try the new update. If it doesn't work, you need to update your question with more details and I'll also delete this answer.

Comment: its oke, ill skip the plot part, it doesn't necessary thanks for the answer